# How to put Code Sample Plugin of TinyMCE in phpfox?

Tags: tinymce, phpfox

I have an tiny mce editor like image bellow:

[image]

and I want to put Code Sample Plugin of tinymce editor in phpfox like:

[image]

Please tell me what should I do.

Comment: what have your tried so far?

Comment: I put the tiny editor in my phpfox project, it's work, but it isn't have code sample i'm tries to use the latest version of tiny editor is 4.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In case you don't have codesample installed, you can download entire bundle from [tinymce.com](http://tinymce.com) and include plugin.min.js from directory js/tinymce/plugins/codesample/
2. Download prism.js and prism.css from [prismjs.com](http://prismjs.com/) and include in your HTML page
3. Modify your tinymce_setup.js and add codesample to your tinymce_setup.js
   My tinymce_setup.js looks like

```js
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  height: 500,
  plugins: [
    'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
    'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
    'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste code codesample'
  ],
  toolbar: ("insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | " +
            "alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | " +
            "bullist numlist outdent indent | link image table | " +
            "code fullscreen codesample"),
});
```